# Firestore - Sanitizing Text Area Input?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I see in the [Writing conditions for Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#custom_functions) documentation that a (server side) custom function can be run against new writes.  My question is: do I even need to worry about sanitizing `textarea` user input before writing/saving that to FireStore, or does Firestore automatically do this?

If I need to sanitize user input, what would a javascript function look like to do that? What characters should I disallow or remove from the string? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firestore does not automatically do any filtering of input. If you want to filter the input, you will have to do so in your own code and/or security rules.

The exact rules depend on your specific needs. The most common things I see are length restrictions, and things like email or phone number validations. More complex rules are definitely possible, but many developers at some point prefer using a Cloud Function to do the sanitization.

Comment: my concern is someone putting javascript in the textarea. Any idea the best way to prevent malicious code from getting passed?

Comment: Firestore doesn't store JavaScript, it just stores the text. You'll want to ensure that you never simply set any user input with `elm.innerHTML`. If the user can input text, store what they input, and set it with `elm.innerText`. A very simple sanitization could be to escape `<` as `&lt;` when adding it to the HTML.